# Declaring a function prototype with FILE as parameter

Tags: c, file, prototype

I'm doing a library in C, and I'm trying to declare the prototype of a  function on .h, but it is getting an error when i try to use this function at main.

This is just happening when i tried to put FILE as a function parameter.

```
/* .h file */
#include<stdlib.h>
void WriteCLient(Lst *aux, FILE *sai);
```

and I'm getting the following errors:

Error   4   error C2059: syntax error : ')' 
Error   2   error C2081: 'FILE' : name in formal parameter list illegal 
Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'

Error   3   error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'

and that

IntelliSense: more than one instance of overloaded function "WriteCLient" matches the argument list:    241

Comment: Try adding `#include <stdio.h>` for a start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void WriteCLient(Lst *aux, FILE *sai);
```

Answer (score 1):

`FILE` type is declared in `stdio.h` not in `stdlib.h`